# Using Mandrill for mass mailings

Tags: mailing, mandrill

Do somebody know if i can use Mandrill as mass mailing, or is there somebody who use Mandrill for mass mailings?

Are there other providers that are compatible with civicrm, for mass mailings?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you definitely can connect CiviCRM to Mandrill for email delivery, including mass emails. Theres also Sparkpost etc. We did a video on the subject if you're interested. https://youtu.be/lQvl4i86Z6Q

Comment: Thanks! For the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Amazon SES with all my CiviCRM accounts now. (I used Mandrill ages ago before monthly fees made it impossible. The I used sendgrid until that kept getting blocked emails due to shared IP addresses.) Amazon AWS is not the easiest to setup, and I have never figured out log reports, but it's super fast and reliable. You must request to get out of the sandbox after setup, and can only send from addresses in authorized domains. Use this extension: https://github.com/mecachisenros/aws

Comment: Nice! I look into it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also find your own SMTP gateway (to send emails with great deliverability) and use Mosaico or traditional mailing within CiviCRM.
We use Alinto, a French provider with a reactive customer service and cheap prices.

Comment: You also get bounces to work with it?

Comment: not yet. I haven't dug into it.